# localStorage data does not show when window reloads

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a mock-up RSVP app, and I can't get the localStorage data to come up when the page refreshes. I am aiming to be able to insert a name and have the name get appended to the invitation list. Then, the user can either repeat those steps for multiple names or edit the names in the list. I have this part down, but if I were to refresh the page, the invitees are no longer in the list below the input bar. I need it to where it will keep the names in the list, and the buttons on the list items (edit, remove) will still work.

With the 'main code' below, the item is added to the localStorage and set as 'rsvp', but the visible list is not updated until I refresh the page. I need it to update every time I hit the submit button. I have tried adding

```
if (rsvp != null) {
   ul.outerHTML = rsvp;
}
```

right below

```
console.log(rsvp);
```

but when I click submit, the list is not updated and in the console you see the data that was loaded the previous time you used the app.

For example, if I type in 'Test', click submit, type in 'Test2', click submit then type in 'Test3' and click submit again - the list is not visibly updated, you get an error in the console saying 'Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'outerHTML' property on 'Element': This element has no parent node.', and the list is never updated until you refresh the page, type in another name and click submit. Again, if you do this, the list is not updated until you repeat the same process.

Main code (*without* the rsvp 'if' statement in the handler)

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

 const form = document.getElementById('registrar');
 const input = form.querySelector('input');

 const mainDiv = document.querySelector('.main');
 const ul = document.getElementById('invitedList');

 const div = document.createElement('div');
 const filterLabel = document.createElement('label');
 const filterCheckbox = document.createElement('input');



 filterLabel.textContent = "Hide those who haven't responded";
 filterCheckbox.type = 'checkbox';
 div.appendChild(filterLabel);
 div.appendChild(filterCheckbox);
 mainDiv.insertBefore(div, ul);

 // Creates the list item for the RSVP list
 function createLI(text) {
     function createElement(elementName, property, value) {
         const element = document.createElement(elementName);
         element[property] = value;
         return element;
     }

     function appendToLI(elementName, property, value) {
         const element = createElement(elementName, property, value);
         li.appendChild(element);
         return element;
     }

     const li = document.createElement('li');
     appendToLI('span', 'textContent', text);
     appendToLI('label','textContent', 'Confirm')
        .appendChild(createElement('input', 'type', 'checkbox'));
     appendToLI('button', 'textContent', 'edit');
     appendToLI('button', 'textContent', 'remove');
     return li;
 }


 form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     const text = input.value;
     input.value = '';

     // Checks for empty string in the input area
     if (text === '') {
         alert("You have not entered a name, please try again.");
         return;
     }
     // Checks for duplicate names
     for (i = 0; i < ul.children.length; i++) {
         if (text === ul.children[i].children[0].textContent) {
             alert("This name has already been entered. Please enter a different name.");
             return;
         }
     }

     const li = createLI(text);
     ul.appendChild(li);

     localStorage.setItem('rsvp', JSON.stringify(ul.outerHTML));  


 });

 const rsvp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('rsvp'));
 if (rsvp != null) {
    ul.outerHTML = rsvp;
 }


 // Changes list item from confirm to confirmed
 ul.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
     const checkbox = event.target;
     const checked = checkbox.checked;
     const label = checkbox.parentNode;
     const listItem = checkbox.parentNode.parentNode;

     if (checked) {
         listItem.className = 'responded';
         label.childNodes[0].textContent = 'Confirmed';
     } else {
         listItem.className = '';
         label.childNodes[0].textContent = 'Confirm';
     }
 });


 ul.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
     if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
         const button = e.target;
         const li = button.parentNode;
         const ul = li.parentNode;
         const action = button.textContent; 
         const nameActions = {
             remove: () => {
                 ul.removeChild(li);
             },
             edit: () => {
                 const span = li.firstElementChild;
                 const input = document.createElement('input');
                 input.type = 'text';
                 input.value = span.textContent;
                 li.insertBefore(input, span);
                 li.removeChild(span);
                 button.textContent = 'save';
             },
             save: () => {
                 const input = li.firstElementChild;
                 const span = document.createElement('span');
                 span.textContent = input.value;
                 li.insertBefore(span, input);
                 li.removeChild(input);
                 button.textContent = 'edit';
             }
         };
         // select and run action in button's name
         nameActions[action]();
     }
 });

 // Filters out those who have not yet responded
 filterCheckbox.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
     const isChecked = e.target.checked;
     const lis = ul.children;

     if (isChecked) {
         for (let i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
             let li = lis[i];
             if (li.className === 'responded') {
                 li.style.display = '';
             } else {
                 li.style.display = 'none';
             }
         }
     } else {
         for (let i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
             let li = lis[i];
             li.style.display = '';
         }
     }

 });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const rsvp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('rsvp'))
```

is called within `DOMContentLoaded` event handler

```
if (rsvp != null) {
  ul.outerHTML = rsvp;
}
```

is called immediately following `.addEventListener()`; also the code at Question does not indicate where `localStorage.getItem('rsvp')` is set before `const rsvp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('rsvp'))` is called.

You can check is `localStorage` has the property key `"rsvp"` before defining `rsvp`, and use `if` condition and statement with `DOMContentLoaded` event handler.

Comment: I've updated the code. Now, it updates and saves the list, but the buttons next to the names have zero functionality.